# How to send a filtered list back to code to export. WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, filter

I have a datagrid on a WPF usercontrol. Currently the list displays maintenance problems per selection. 
When a user loads up the info, they are presented with 50 records returned from the database:
 [image]
The user can then filter a column:

[image]

And the list now displays the filtered items:
[image]

As you can clearly see, the filtered list has less records/rows in the grid. 
My problem is when I click my export to excel button, I still get the list that has 50 items. How can I send back the filtered List?

My code to load the list:

```
GenericSearchRequest genericSearchRequest = new GenericSearchRequest()
                {
                    AuthKey = ApplicationState.authResponse.AuthKey,
                    PropertyValues = propertyValues
                };
                getMainCallProblemsResponse = reportManagementClient.GetMaintenanceReports(genericSearchRequest);
                if (!getMainCallProblemsResponse.IsError)
                maintenanceReportsList = new ObservableCollection<MainCallProblems>(getMainCallProblemsResponse.MCProblems);

            };
```

This returns the 50 records from the DB. I have put this into my grid: `ItemsSource="{Binding maintenanceReportsList, Mode=TwoWay}"` to try and capture any changes that might occur on the grid, but that didn't change it.

When I click the button:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            try
            {
                saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xls";
                saveFileDialog.Filter = "Execl files (.xls)|*.xls";
                if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    C1XLBook book = new C1XLBook();
                    XLSheet sheet = book.Sheets[0];
                    //Set headers
                    sheet[0, 0].Value = "Township";
                    sheet[0, 1].Value = "Erf Number";
                    sheet[0, 2].Value = "Portion Number";
                    sheet[0, 3].Value = "Object Number";
                    sheet[0, 4].Value = "Object Description";
                    sheet[0, 5].Value = "Maintenance Type";
                    sheet[0, 6].Value = "Problem Reference Number";
                    sheet[0, 8].Value = "Problem Description";
                    sheet[0, 9].Value = "Priority";
                    sheet[0, 10].Value = "Sector";
                    sheet[0, 11].Value = "Element";
                    sheet[0, 12].Value = "Component";
                    sheet[0, 13].Value = "Service Avenue";
                    sheet[0, 14].Value = "Cost Estimate";
                    sheet[0, 15].Value = "Superintendent";
                    sheet[0, 16].Value = "Assistant";
                    sheet[0, 17].Value = "Job Card Number";
                    sheet[0, 18].Value = "Cost Description";
                    sheet[0, 19].Value = "Item Price";
                    sheet[0, 20].Value = "Item Quantity";
                    sheet[0, 21].Value = "Total Cost";
                    sheet[0, 7].Value = "Date & Time Captured";

                    //Write content for each row
                    int i = 0;
                    OnPropertyChanged(null);
                    foreach (var item in maintenanceReportsList)
                    {
                        i++;
                        sheet[i, 0].Value = item.Township;
                        sheet[i, 1].Value = item.ErfNo;
                        sheet[i, 2].Value = item.PortionNo;
                        sheet[i, 3].Value = item.ObjectNo;
                        sheet[i, 4].Value = item.ObjectDescription;
                        sheet[i, 5].Value = item.MaintenanceType;
                        sheet[i, 6].Value = item.ProblemRefNo;
                        sheet[i, 8].Value = item.ProblemDescription;
                        sheet[i, 9].Value = item.Priority;
                        sheet[i, 10].Value = item.Sector;
                        sheet[i, 11].Value = item.Element;
                        sheet[i, 12].Value = item.Component;
                        sheet[i, 13].Value = item.ServiceAvenue;
                        sheet[i, 14].Value = item.CostEstimate;
                        sheet[i, 15].Value = item.SuperintendentName;
                        sheet[i, 16].Value = item.AssistantName;
                        sheet[i, 17].Value = item.JobCardNo;
                        sheet[i, 18].Value = item.CostDescription;
                        sheet[i, 19].Value = item.ItemPrice;
                        sheet[i, 20].Value = item.ItemQty;
                        sheet[i, 21].Value = item.TotalCost;
                        sheet[i, 7].Value = item.TimeDate;
                    }

                    book.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
                    args.Result = "Success";
                }
                else
                    args.Result = "Cancelled";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                BugsBase bug = new BugsBase(ex.ToString(), ApplicationState.authResponse.UserIntrecno, this.ToString(), 0, "Maintenance: export to excel");
                args.Result = "Failed";
            }
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Result.ToString() == "Success")
                MessageView.ShowBox(GeneralMessages.ExportSuccessfulMessage);
            else if (args.Result.ToString() == "Failed")
                MessageView.ShowBox(GeneralMessages.ErrorMessage);
        };
```

I tried to add that OnPropertyChanged(null), above the foreach loop, which is a control we use to refresh the usercontrol. It doesn't however change the list, because that is what stays at 50, and doesn't fetch the new filtered list from the grid to export to excel.

Please could someone tell me where I've gone wrong and how do I fix this?

Just a heads up. I have no problem with the SAVING to excel function. Just what is being saved.

Comment: Not sure what grid this is, but Is filtering built in?  I'd go and find the docs for this.  I expect you'll have to get the filtered `ICollectionView`, as the grid won't change the 'full' list of items when filtering.

Comment: This is a Component 1 (C1) grid. They don't have much on their website. And the forums take forever for someone to answer. Thought I would try my luck on Stack first